# DockableFrame title font color

Tags: java, dockable

I would like to change the font color for DockableFrame's title and i've tried using UIManager etc but it still doesn't work. My code below tried using custom label component and UIManager:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    UIManager.put("DockableFrameTitlePane.showIcon", true);
    UIManager.put("DockableFrame.titleForeground", Color.red);

    DockableFrame dock = bnew DockableFrame("Title", myIcon);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Jlabel Title");
    label.setForeground(Color.green);
    dock.setTitleLabelComponent(label);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(dock);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

What was displayed was a dockable frame titled "JLabel Frame" in black text with my custom icon. How do i actually change the font color?